# To restrict the multi entity lookup using javascript in MSCRM 2015

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

Am trying to restrict the entities list in regarding object lookup in task entity. document.getElementById('regardingobjectid").getAttribute("lookuptypenames") is returning null in 2015 whereas in crm 2011 it is working fine. is there any way to get all the entity listed in multi entity lookup in crm 2015?.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
document.getElementById("regardingobjectid_i").getAttribute("lookuptypenames")
```

Comment: But the same is not working for appointment entity. Tried with id what I do from the page.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("customerid").setAttribute("lookuptypes", "1");
```

will restrict customer to `Account`